# Am I bloating my coding with IF statements?

Tags: php

I was wondering, do too many IF statements bloat coding and when is it okay not to use them?

These two examples both work the same and I'm the only one editing / using the script. Am I teaching myself bad habits by not adding the IF statement?

```
if ($en['mm_place']) {
    $tmp = explode(",", $en['mm_place']);
    $en['mm_place'] = $tmp[0].", ".$tmp[1]." ".$tmp[2];
}
```

is the same as...

```
$tmp = explode(",", $en['mm_place']);
$en['mm_place'] = $tmp[0].", ".$tmp[1]." ".$tmp[2];
```

**EDIT: using @Francis Avila example I came up with this...**

```
if ($en['mm_wmeet']) {
    $tmp = explode(",", $en['mm_wmeet']);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($tmp); $i++) {
        $en['mm_wmeet'] = $tmp[$i];
    }
}
```

Comment: also consider using sprintf instead of string concatenation

Comment: Use the `IF..` whenever you need to. If you don't need to make any checks beforehand, (as what `IF` statements are used a lot for) then don't use it.. If you do, then don't hesitate. It'd be better to have loads of `IF` statements than not have any kind of checking/validation that leads to your code exploding with errors or doing the wrong things..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular example, they are not the same.

If `$en['mm_place']` is empty, then `$tmp` will not have three elements, so your string construction will be bogus.

Actually what you need is probably this:

```
if (!empty($en['mm_place'])) { // depending on whether you know if this is set and must be a string.
    $tmp = explode(',', $en['mm_place'], 3);
    if (count($tmp)===3) {
        $en['mm_place'] = "{$tmp[0]}, {$tmp[1]} {$tmp[2]}";
    }
}
```

Run PHP with `E_NOTICE` set, and code in such a way that you don't get any notices. PHP requires an extraordinary amount of discipline to use safely and properly because it has so many sloppy misfeatures. Notices will inform you of most bad practices. You will probably end up using lots of `if` statements.

Comment: this got me thinking what if for some reason there is only 2 elements? shouldn't it be more dynamic instead of hard coding the code let the code search and determine the count? would that be a better way to do it?

Comment: It depends entirely on what you are trying to accomplish--not at the code-level but at the task-level. What are the range of acceptable inputs and outputs?

Comment: Your second example makes no sense! The entire for-loop is the same as `$en['mm_wmeet']=$tmp[count($tmp)-1]`. Please don't give *me* credit for this! I think your problem is not code bloat but not thinking clearly about your problem. You need to step back from the keyboard and think about your program in terms of what it should accept and what it should output, and do it with *words* not code.

Comment: `if (!empty($en['mm_place']))`  does not guaranty that variable is a string it can be array or string containing 0

Answer (score 1):

if they don't serve any purpose then yes, you're bloating.

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of situation, where you are checking if an array element exists before operating on it, you should keep the if-statement in the code.  Here it will only throw a notice if the element is missing, but in the future you definitely could have similar code that will crash if the element is not set.

Edit: Actually those two code samples are **not** the same.  if `$en['mm_place']` is null or not set, the first sample will leave it as such while the second will replace it with `", "`